# React mutation with graphql and strapi-'return' outside of function

Tags: reactjs, graphql, strapi

I'm trying to update existing data collection on strapi with a new enter. using strapi and GraphQL in the backhand and react on the front.

[image]

```
import React from 'react'
import { useMutation, gql } from '@apollo/client'


    const CREATE_REVEIW = gql`
    mutation {
    createReveiw(input: { data: {body:“Lorem ipsum dolor sit am”,title: “avitesttesting”, rating: 5} }) {
    reveiw {
    body
    title
    rating
    } } } `;
    
    export default function AddTodo() {
        const [createReveiw, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(CREATE_REVEIW);}
        console.log(data);
      
        if (loading) return 'Submitting...';
        if (error) return `Submission error! ${error.message}`;
      
        return (
          
            <div className="review-card">
              <div className="rating">{data.reveiw.rating}</div>
              <h2>{data.reveiw.title}</h2>
        
              {data.reveiw.categories.map(c => (
                <small key={c.id}>{c.name}</small>
              ))}
        
              <p>{data.reveiw.body}</p>
            </div>
          )
```

I am getting an err:

> SyntaxError: C:\graphy\graphy2\src\pages\AddTodo.js: 'return' outside of function.    data' is not defined  loading' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `}` in the end of line:

```
const [createReveiw, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(CREATE_REVEIW);}
```

So just remove it and update like this:

```
export default function AddTodo() {
  const [createReveiw, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(CREATE_REVEIW);
  console.log(data);

  if (loading) return "Submitting...";
  if (error) return `Submission error! ${error.message}`;

  return (
    <div className="review-card">
      <div className="rating">{data.reveiw.rating}</div>
      <h2>{data.reveiw.title}</h2>

      {data.reveiw.categories.map((c) => (
        <small key={c.id}>{c.name}</small>
      ))}

      <p>{data.reveiw.body}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks, i still getting an err:Uncaught GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Cannot parse the unexpected character "\u201C".
    at syntaxError (syntaxError.mjs:8)